# How to execute diff on outputs of two scripts without creating temporary files?

Tags: bash

I've got two programs: p3, p4 and one input file: 1.in. I want to check if p3 and p4 outputs are the same for 1.in input file and nothing that I write works. I want to do this without creating new files (I simply want to know how to do this to better know bash). I tried some naive combinations like:

```
diff (./p3 < 1.in) (./p4< 1.in)
```

But it doesn't work of course. Can anyone help? I'm using ubuntu 11.04.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [process substitution](http://www.gnu.org/s/bash/manual/html_node/Process-Substitution.html) in bash to compare the outputs of two commands.  For example, try:

```
 diff <(./p3 < 1.in) <(./p4 < 1.in)
```

(And for prettier output you could use `colordiff` instead of `diff` :))